# How to generate and manipulate JavaScript ESTree AST in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, compiler-construction, code-generation, abstract-syntax-tree

There is a ESTree spec describing JavaScript AST format, which is used in several libraries for JS code transformations (refactoring, transpiling, minification, etc).

Are there any tools/libraries with API focused on **generating** the ESTree AST from scratch (not from existing JS code) and manipulate it? Preferably in TypeScript to get the advantage of static typing of ESTree nodes.

Comment: Have a look at compiler api https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#creating-and-printing-a-typescript-ast

Comment: @AlekseyL. thanks, it says "TypeScript AST", but since it's a "superset", I should be able to use it for pure JS too, right?

Comment: I think so. Just don't generate "type" nodes if you don't need them.

Comment: TS shouldn't be ESTree compatible. To get it so, you might look at `@typescript-eslint`, though it seems it is focused more on parsing from source.

Comment: You might look into https://github.com/jamiebuilds/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md#builders to conveniently generate Babel AST, and then use https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-to-estree to convert it to ESTree, but it seems per their roadmap that Babel still has work to align their types fully with TS, so unless babel-to-estree does it, TS generation might be lacking.

Comment: Should be pretty easy with `estree-toolkit` - https://www.npmjs.com/package/estree-toolkit